# Who normally attends a residential real estate closing in the US?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, real-estate, minnesota

For a standard mortgage closing, what parties are usually in attendance for the final walkthrough and closing event?

Comment: The answer will vary state to state. Certain roles played by real estate attorneys are sometimes played by title companies in other states, for instance. Can you tell us what state you're interested in?

Comment: Minnesota, specifically

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with Minnesota but this may be helpful: https://www.ag.state.mn.us/Consumer/Handbooks/HmSellers/CH6.asp

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it's the buyer and the representative of the seller (either a realtor, lawyer or a title company). The seller can choose to participate, if so inclined.

I'd add that there may be different requirements in different states.

Answer (score 1):

The buyers and sellers are represented at the walk though. The person who represents each side has to have the power to address any issues.  If there is a surprise that has to be addressed, then delays while getting permission will impact the closing. Not all buyers and not all sellers must be there, but both sides need to be represented. Frequently the real estate agents also participate.

Closing is a separate thing. Everybody that has to sign a form must be there, or be represented by somebody with power of attorney.

Comment: Not really. The seller and the buyer can sign at different times, in different locations, if travelling is inconvenient. I bought this way; my seller was 3000 miles away and signed some days before.

Answer (score 0):

I recently sold and bought in NJ. Closing during the purchase was handled by my lawyer. I didn't attend but instead signed a few days before.

When I sold, I attended the closing with my lawyer, my real estate agent, the titling company, and the buyer. My mortgage broker showed up as well but wasn't necessary.